# Deciding on customer id and saving payment method after transaction in Braintree

Tags: braintree

I would like to have the following workflow on our website with Braintree payment gateway: a customer which is or isn't logged in pays with a credit card (using Braintree hosted fields). If the payment is successful and customer is not logged in, we offer him to login or register in order to save the payment method.

Unfortunately, that means that in Transaction.sale I cannot use the existing customer id, since the customer is not yet logged in our system. And after the transaction is complete, I cannot reuse payment nonce to create payment method and assign it to our customer.

One possibility I am considering is to always vault the payment method during transaction (with a new Braintree customer id) and than to assign this customer id to our user's account if he logs in. However, that can result in one user having multiple Braintree customer ids which would complicate later payments with saved cards. (Plus I have to vault a lot of fake customers and payment methods that will never be used again since majority of our customers never create user accounts.) Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to [contact support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sup>

You are correct. To achieve this flow you would need to create a new customer and payment method each time. The good news is that `Transaction.sale` does not require a customer id, just a [payment method token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/#payment_method_token), so you can associate the payment method token with your app's customer id and you won't need to maintain a relation to the customers in the Braintree control panel.

For clean up, you could do the following:

1) If the user declines the option to save the payment method, delete the customer and payment method token immediately.

2) If the user closes the application without making a decision one way or the other, you could have a periodic process to clean up unclaimed customers and payment method tokens.